# What qualifies as a system program?

Tags: operating-system

I've seen some references to "system programs" and wasn't 100% what they are. Reading a definition hasn't cleared it up for me. Is any program considered a "system program"? Or is it more specific than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say there's a clear definition. Debasish's definition is sometimes used, but sometimes "system program" means something that operates at a system-wide (rather than user-specific) level, and so requires root access (Linux) or administrator privileges (Windows).

Answer (score 1):

usually, programs having direct call to operating system kernel APIs are termed as somewhat system programs